# How do I create a custom Select lambda expression at runtime to work with sub classes

Tags: linq, lambda, runtime, compilation, expression-trees

If I have following type hierarchy:

```
abstract class TicketBase
{
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
}

class TicketTypeA:TicketBase
{
     public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}   

class TicketTypeB:TicketBase
{
     public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

and many more `TicketTypes : TicketBase`

and want to create a function which selects any property e.g.  `PropertyA` from  any ticket type e.g. `TicketTypeA`

I wrote this function:

```
    private Func<TicketBase, String> CreateSelect(Type t, String FieldName)
    {
        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(t, "sel");
        var fieldProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExp, FieldName);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TicketBase, String>>(fieldProp, parameterExp);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
```

and call it on a `List<TicketBase> Tickets` like so:

```
Type typeToSelectFrom = typeof(TicketTypeA);
String propertyToSelect = "PropertyA";
Tickets.Select(CreateSelect(typeToSelectFrom, propertyToSelect));
```

I get the following ArgumentException:

```
ParameterExpression of type 'TicketTypes.TicketTypeA' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'Types.TicketBase'
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *one* option is to include a cast, e.g.

```
private Func<TicketBase, String> CreateSelect(Type t, String FieldName)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TicketBase), "sel");
    var cast = Expression.Convert(parameterExp, t);
    var fieldProp = Expression.PropertyOrField(cast, FieldName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TicketBase, String>>(fieldProp,
                                                             parameterExp);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

So that calling `CreateSelect(typeof(TicketTypeA), "PropertyA")` is equivalent to:

```
Func<TicketBase, string> func = tb => ((TicketTypeA)tb).PropertyA;
```

Obviously that's going to fail if you apply it to a `TicketBase` value which refers to (say) a `TicketTypeB`, but it's hard to avoid that, if you've got a `List<TicketBase>` or something similar.

Comment: Great, this works - thanks Jon. But I'm intrigued by your emphasis on this being _one_ option.. are there any better options?

Comment: @cjroebuck: Well, you could potentially make it a generic method to return a `Func<T, string>` - but it's not clear whether you *always* know the type that you're going to call it with at compile time (as you do here).

Comment: Well, I know that it is _always_ going to be a type `T : TicketBase` but I dont know _which_ `T` until run-time

Comment: @cjroebuck: Sure, but if you don't know the type itself at compile time, you can't easily call it as a generic method.