# How to Passing multiple parameters RelayCommand?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing two command parameters using a WPF binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding)

I need that send two parameters to my RelayCommand like:

```
public RelayCommand<String,Int> MyCommand {get;set;} Or
public RelayCommand<EventArgument,String> MyCommand {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap them in an object:

```
public RelayCommand<MyModel> MyCommand { get; set; }
```

where MyModel will contain the two properties:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: in fact i want send to mycommand :RelayCommand<EventArgument,ControlName>

Comment: @mtaboy, the way RelayCommand is defined, there is only one type you can pass. So if you want multiple types you will have to wrap them into a separate model as shown in my answer.

Comment: How can you set Id And Name in  xaml code as  MyModel
?

Comment: @mtaboy, your main view model could have a property of this type. Then you could use the CommandParameter with the correct binding syntax.

Comment: you are Right..But, How can I set Name And Id Property in Xaml code?

Answer (score 9):

You can use a distinct model class in order to pass several parameters. And in order to initialize them, you can use xaml elements like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding YourCommand}">
   <Button.CommandParameter>
      <YourNS:YourModel Id="{Binding PathForId}" Name="{Binding PathForName}"/>
   </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

This will construct a new YourModel object to pass to a command, and then will initialize its properties via bindings.

Comment: Actually this didn't end up working out for me in Silverlight. Instead I used the custom multibinding class mentioned in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286171/MultiBinding-in-Silverlight-5 - no converter is needed, you just need to cast the object in to an object[].