# How to pass Multiple parameters as CommandParameter in InvokeCommandAction in Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I read this posing about passing multiple parameters as commandParameter in InvokeCommandAction:
[How to pass Multiple parameters as CommandParameter in InvokeCommandAction In WPF App Using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601684/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-as-commandparameter-in-invokecommandaction-in-wp)
But that solution is for WPF.

I want to do the same on Windows phone 8.1. The IMultiValueConverter is not available on Windows phone.

How can I do solve it on windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a model that contains your mulit parameters.

eg:

```
public class ParameterModel
{
    public string A { get; set;}
    public string B { get; set;}
}
```

and in your CommandParameter you can bind the model