# WPF Passing ViewModel as Multi Param

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a listview which lists years and another list view which has year groups.
The year group list view is populated using a ICollectionView filter on selectchanged of the first listview.

I want to add a new record to the groups, but I need the ID of the selecteditem in the year list view as the foreignkey.

I declare 2 static viewmodel resources in the XML. One the list and one a new empty group.

```
<local:YearGroupListViewModel x:Key="YearGroupList" />
<local:YearGroupViewModel x:Key="NewYearGroup" />
```

In order to create new records on other pages I successfully pass the new viewmodel as a parameter to the add command (example of year):

```
<Button x:Name="btnSettingsYearsSaveAdd" x:Uid="btnSettingsYearsSaveAdd" 
    Content="Submit" Margin="0,49,10,0" 
    Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
    DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=YearList}"
    CommandParameter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewYear}" 
    Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}" />
```

This works fine on records that do not have a dependency on a parent listviews selecteditem id for foreign key purposes.

So I am trying to use the multi parameter pass mentioned in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding)

My problem is that I cannot seem to pass the New Group View Model as a parameter as I can if only sending one parameter.

This is where I am at the moment:

XML

```
<Button x:Name="btnSettingsYearGroupsSaveAdd" x:Uid="btnSettingsYearGroupsSaveAdd"
    Content="Submit" Margin="0,49,10,0" 
    Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
    DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=YearGroupList}" 
    Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource paramConvert}">
                <Binding Path="YearGroup" 
                         ElementName="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewYearGroup}"/>
                <Binding Path="SelectedItem" 
                         ElementName="lvwSettingsYears"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
```

The static resource key binding does not work. I have tried a dozen different derivatives, but all fail.

Command

```
public void OnExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var values = (object[])parameter;
        YearGroupViewModel newYearGroup = values[0] as YearGroupViewModel;
        yearID = (Int32)values[1];
    }
```

Has anyone done this before? Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess it should be `Source` not `ElementName`, if you try to bind a `StaticResource`.

```
<Button x:Name="btnSettingsYearGroupsSaveAdd" x:Uid="btnSettingsYearGroupsSaveAdd"
        Content="Submit" Margin="0,49,10,0" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=YearGroupList}" 
        Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource paramConvert}">
            <Binding Path="YearGroup" 
                     Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewYearGroup}"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem" 
                     ElementName="lvwSettingsYears"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you DHN. I eventually went down a new rabbit hole with this... but you answered my question and now I know :) Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. We all start with new things. Nothing to be ashamed of. :o)