# how to send argument from xaml to code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

In my xaml page i have a delete button that will delete item for each line with the id of the item. I want to send id when i clicked the button.

In WPF, how to do that?

I found only the way to send multiple values as the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding/1350995#1350995).

Comment: You need to post some code so that we can see exactly what you are trying to achieve? Whats the item? Is it in a listbox? A combobox? What is the method we are sending the id too? ... Please spend a little time on your question and read the rules.

Comment: what you have trying?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at this with the little information provided.  I assume that some item is selected. And when you click the delete button, you want to remove that item from your list.  In this case, you should set the item.Tag to the ID value, or to some object that contains the ID value.  Then, when you click 'Delete' you can get the selected item from the list you are deleting from, look at that selected item's Tag, and get the ID that you need from it.  Then, you can zip through the list using the ID you just got to determine which other items in the list need to be deleted.

Hope this helps. Send more clarification if this doesn't help, and I'll try to give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you. It is what you said. I want to delete the item that I have selected. But I don't know how to do that. Please give me the sample.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is a CommandParameter. Lets assume that you have a ViewModel set up as a static resource in your page and a ListBox binding to a collection of items that utilises a DataTemplate.

What you're going to need to achieve this is in your ViewModel create an ICommand to handle the delete.

```
public ICommand DeleteItemCommand {
    get { return new DelegateCommand(deleteItemClicked, alwaysCanInvoke); }
}

private deleteItemClicked(object param) {
 // Business logic here to remove item based on param
}
```

Next in your XAML DataTemplate you specify the following.

```
<Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=DeleteItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
```

Where Id is the exposed property of the item you're attempting to remove from your list.

For an example of implementing a DelegateCommand have a look here: http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html

Hope this helps.