# wpf reusable template for DataGrid header

Tags: c#, wpf

Here I designed a DataTemplate to be used in a DataGrid's header in order to provide UI for filtering.
It's just a button added to the standard content of the header.
The button has a Command that points back to the template's host class.
The easiest possible starting point.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myFilterHeader">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            <Button Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                    Command="{Binding FilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                <Path Fill="DarkBlue" Width="11px" Stretch="Uniform" >
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="m 242.678 412.212 h -73.143 c -15.05738 0 -15.673 -0.30785 -15.673 -15.673 V 256.45921 L 10.71 24.555 C 7.053 19.853 -0.42883798 0.02223789 -0.42883798 0.02223789 -0.42883798 0.02223789 16.98 0 23.249 0 h 365.714 c 5.747 0 23.67784 0.33100686 23.67784 0.33100686 0 0 -7.48184 19.52199314 -11.13884 24.22399314 L 258.351 256.45921 V 396.539 c 0 14.43884 1.85353 15.673 -15.673 15.673 z m -57.47 -31.347 h 41.796 V 251.23521 c 0 -3.135 1.045 -6.792 3.135 -9.404 L 358.139 30.825 H 54.073 l 128 211.00621 c 2.09 2.612 3.135 5.747 3.135 9.404 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

[image: Data Grid with templated column header]

My intention is to reuse this across multiple Datagrid around the application.
What prevents me to do so is the command pattern; consider the line:

```
            <Button Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                    Command="{Binding FilterCommand, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                              AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding Content}">
```

it works because my datacontext class has the property:

```
public ICommand FilterCommand { get; } = new SimpleFilterCommand();
```

that in turn points to my fitering implementation.

If I have multiple DataGrid in the same window, I would like to point to different FilterCommand properties, one per grid let's say, using the very same template "myFilterHeader".
How can I do that? If it's not feasible, how can achieve this in a more wpf-friendly way?
Consider that this template is  deliberately simple just to fit in a sample.  In the real application it will be more complex, that's why i'm looking for reusability strategies.

Comment: Did you already thought about filtering depending on the passed parameter? So you would be able to solve this in a single command by differing based on the parameter.

Comment: I would use `MultiBinding` for `CommandParameter` and bind to something else which indicates which collection to sort. Could be `Tag` or a `Name`, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1350995/2289942