# Pass one Binding and one constant string as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a button and want to pass multiple command parameter one being Binding and one is a constant string (in this case a constant string `TDS`)

I am trying to follow this link: [Passing two command parameters using a WPF binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding) but this is for multibinding. In my case I am using 1 binding and one constant string. I tried the below but it is giving syntax error in VS.

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding>
        <Binding Path="."/>
        <s:String>TDS</s:String>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource yourConverter}">
        <Binding Path="."/>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Source>
                <s:String>TDS</s:String>
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>            
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

If your string is defined in resources you can reference it this way:

```
...
<x.Resources>
    <s:String x:Key="stringKey">TDS</s:String>
</x.Resources>
...
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource yourConverter}">
        <Binding Path="."/>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource stringKey}" />       
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

As mentioned in the comment a converter must be specified for `MultiBinding`.

Comment: MultiBinding needs a Converter to produce a value.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I know. Not clear if it's copy paste error in question because in linked SO answer the converter is not missing.

Comment: thanks it worked. I know converter was missing. I just wanted to fix the compile time error first. Your answer is perfect.