# How to pass multiple parameters to Telerik:RadButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have 2 telerik:RadGridView object  (named FTP and Email grid) separated by pagetabs that a user can choose multiple records from by clicking a row. I need to pass those 2 telerik:RadGridView
objects after the user clicks on OK as I need to know which records were selected by the user and from which grid they belong(whether EmailGrid or FTPGrid). I've read how to do multiple bindings from this link:

[Passing two command parameters using a WPF binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding)

but I'm not sure how to add them to my code as the syntax seems different because we are using telerik.

Our code looks like this:

```
<telerik:RadButton Content="Select Client" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" 
Command="{Binding SelectClientCommand}" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" 
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=gridEmail}" />  <----- This is where I want to pass my 2 grid objects
```

and the suggestion from the link above seems to have a different syntax:

```
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
         <Binding Path="..." ElementName="MyTextBox"/>
         <Binding Path="..." ElementName="MySomethingElse"/>
     </MultiBinding>
```

I can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: "the syntax seems different because we are using telerik" - using telerik or not doesn't make any difference

Comment: Why you can't use the properties in your VM which will be binded to properties in MyTextBos and MySomethingElse controls?